# How does one define area on the complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, area, plane-geometry

I have been thinking, that due to how functions and numbers can go onto the complex plane, and circles can be inscribed over that, such as that shown by e<sup>i * a</sup>, and it leaves me wondering how exactly one would define and show area in this plane.

For example, what is the area of a unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: You can identify the complex plane with the ordinary Euclidean plane, and all the usual notions of area (and length, and angle, and so on) go over.

Comment: So area in the complex plane does not go into using complex numbers to define it? If so, that makes sense intuitively. I just know mathematics does not always care about intuition, as Gabriel's Horn shows us.

Comment: Mathematics always cares about intuition – but, sometimes it defies it.

Comment: Fair. But I mostly meant that not everything is as it first seems, fractals, a lot of calculus (I mean, heck, Calculus is built upon paradoxes), etc. It does not always follow by what one would instantly assume. It all makes sense once you break it down, but not directly on the surface.

Comment: @Zoey you may be interested in exploring how different metrics lead to different definitions of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

Using Green's theorem to find the area bounded by a closed contour $C$,

\begin{align}
  A &= \frac{1}{2} \oint_C x\, dy-y\, dx \\
  &= \frac{1}{4i} \oint_C \bar z \, dz-z \, d\bar z \\
  &= \frac{1}{2i} \oint_C \bar z \, dz \\
\end{align}

Comment: What exactly does the integral with the circle mean? I recognize integrals and how to work with them, but not the  one with a circle, or what z¯ is means.

Comment: Circle in integration sign means over **closed** curve $C$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks

Comment: $\bar z$ means conjugate of $z$.